# Where is target folder on USB booted Debian?

Tags: debian, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

I need to fix some stuff on my debian sitting on my hard disk.
So I booted from an USB, as it has its own `ash` shell.
The file system is mounted to `/target` (so it says), but there is no folder called like this.

Where is it?  Is it even mounted?
How can I access the data on the hard disk drive?

Comment: Use the command `mount` to see what is mounted where.  Do you see the from your Debian install mounted?   If not, then mount it.

Comment: There is no mount command aviable

Comment: That seems extremely unlikely, if your USB drive has some form of Linux on it.  Then download and use a better livecd.  I am a big fan of http://www.sysresccd.org/